# Can I increase my lifespan by killing myself using the Death Note?

Tags: death-note

Suppose I wrote that I will be killed by a UFO falling from space in the year 2315 while I am lifting.

Will the Note increase my lifespan? In other words, will I still be alive by then?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No. There are some rules that prevent this. From the [Rules of the Death Note wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note):

1. The **23-days rule**

   > ### How to use: XXVII
   >
   > 1. [...]
   > 2. If you write, “die of disease” for the cause of death, but only write a specific time of death without the actual name of disease, the human will die from an adequate disease. **But the Death Note can only operate within 23 days (in the human calendar). This is called the 23-day rule.**
2. Situation/cause of death is impossible

   > ### How to Use: LIV
   >
   > 1. [...]
   > 2. In the occasion where the cause of death is possible but the situation is not, only the cause of death will take effect for that victim. **If both the cause and the situation are impossible, that victim will die of heart attack.**

   While an UFO falling on your head is technically unlikely, but not impossible, the fact that you'll be naturally alive by 2315 is impossible. You'll just shorten your life, not make it longer.
3. Setting death after original lifespan

   > ### How to Use: LVII
   >
   > 1. In the Death Note, you cannot set the death date longer than the victim’s original life span. Even if the victim’s death is set in the Death Note beyond his/her original life span, the victim will die before the set time.

Comment: But going to the main point of the question "Can I increase my lifespan by killing myself using the Death Note?". Can I use it to guaranty my 120 years? Let's say, I was born in 2000. So I wrote heart attack 2120. This will make sure that I'll live for 120 years?

Comment: @MichelAyres The answer is still no. I added two more rules from the Death Note that prevent this.

Answer (score 16):

No. There is a rule specifically against that:

> In the Death Note, you cannot set the death date longer than the victim’s original life span. Even if the victim’s death is set in the Death Note beyond his/her original life span, the victim will die before the set time.

So basically, you'll die of a natural (or whatever your end-of-lifespan-death would be) death before what's written in the Death Note would take effect.

Answer (score -3):

it wouldn't work, because it's beyond your lifespan. but let's say, if you would ask someone with shinigami eyes if he can tell you, your remaining lifespan you could figure out your death date, and then write something like: [your name] dies peacefully at the 3rd may 2087 (just an example). i think this could work because, you still would die on your date of death.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, as the highest-voted answer states. The Death Note does not work for dates more than 23 days away.

Comment: you can give yourself, for example bradykardie which is a disease, and it's stated, the 23 day rule does not take effect when you give yourself a disease. so, can you escape the 23 day rule? yes. but you can't life till 2315.

Comment: The example you gave used a date in 2087. That is more than 23 days away.

Comment: yes its more than 23 days. but if you think about it, alone with the 23 day rule you prolong someones life. because after you wrote the name of a person, he would simply die 40 seconds later if you don't write a cause or a time of death. but let's say, you decide your victim will die 23 days later, if you wouldn't set a time or a cause of death, his life would end after 40 seconds. so basically, his lifespan, would be over then. but you gave him 23 days more, so he wouldn't die when his lifespan is over... so basically i think this still could work. btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: The point is simply that you *wrote a date which is more than 23 days away*. We're not talking about cases where you don't write a time or date. The example in your answer **does** use a date, and that date violates the 23-day rule.

Comment: so if you would write: bob zortö dies after his lifespan is over. would that work?

Comment: I would have to guess no, since after your lifespan is over, you're already dead.

Comment: I should have explained it better. So, if i would write: Bob Zortö dies peacefully after his lifespan comes to an end. Would that work?

Comment: No, for the same reason. After his lifespan comes to an end, he is already dead. Regardless, this conversation has gone on too long. The fact remains that your answer states incorrect information. If you'd like to discuss further, then once you've earned 20 reputation, you can come to [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) and we can continue.