# Death Note 23 Day rule?

Tags: death-note

Okay, first read [this rule](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LVII):

> In the Death Note, you cannot set the death date longer than the victim’s original life span. Even if the victim’s death is set in the Death Note beyond his/her original life span, the victim will die before the set time.

So that means if you wrote something like John zeurtö dies peacefully in the year 2315, that wouldn't work because this date is beyond his lifespan. But that would mean, if you wrote a date thats within his actual lifespan, that would work.

But now, there's this [23 day rule](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVII).

> The Death Note can only operate within 23 days (in the human calendar). This is called the 23 day rule.

So, could the first example work?

Comment: If his original lifespan ends at or after 2315, then it should be fine - the rules here aren't inconsistent.

Comment: Isn't the 23 days rule something Light wrote to trick some one and not something the Ryuk wrote?

Comment: Fake rules: 1) If the owner of the Death Note does not write a name in it for 13 days, he or she will die. 
2) If the Death Note is burned or destroyed, all who have touched it will die.  They were written to trick L. the 23 days is a "real" rule.

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11514/274

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Basically John will die at a given moment, which is...**

- ...before his original lifespan would have ended (Because of [How to Use: LVII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LVII))

  > In the Death Note, you cannot set the death date longer than the victim's original life span. Even if the victim's death is set in the Death Note beyond his/her original life span, the victim will die before the set time.
- ...within 23 days of writing, because a specific time of death was written (Because of [How to Use: XXVII, rule number 2](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVII))

  > If you write, die of disease for the cause of death, but only write **a specific time of death without the actual name of disease**, the human will die from an adequate disease. But the Death Note can only operate within 23 days (in the human calendar). This is called the 23 day rule.

In our case that would be *dying peacefully* instead of *disease*, because the actual way John is supposed to die is not specified. He could die in a coma, could die after being drugged or by sexual exhaustion as mentioned in [kaine's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/12799/6166).

- ...after 6 minutes and 40 seconds if none of those 23 days were in the year 2315 or if it wasn't possible for John to die peacefully within those 23 days due to war for example (Because of [How to Use: XI, rule number 3](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XI))

  > As you see above, the time and conditions of death can be changed, but once the victim's name has been written, the individual's death can never be avoided.

**Therefore, if you write *John zeurtö dies peacefully in the year 2315* one of the following will happen.**

1. 2315 is after his original lifespan; John will die as he normally would have.
2. 2315 is after 23 days of writing; John will die of a heart attack after 6 minutes and 40 seconds.
3. 2315 is before 23 days of writing, but it is impossible for John to die peacefully; He will die of a heart attack after 6 minutes and 40 seconds.
4. 2315 is before 23 days of writing and it is possible to die peacefully; He will die peacefully within those days on the most probable date.

---

Now if you would have written "John dies peacefully of sexual exhaustion", **without mentioning a specific time**, then he might have died later than those 23 days, if it was still within his original lifespan (Because of [How to Use: XXVIII, rule number 1](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVIII))

> If you write die of disease like before **with a specific disease's name, but without a specific time**, if it takes more than 24 days for the human to die the 23 day rule will not take effect and the human will die at an adequate time depending on the disease.

Comment: @user6399 Why did you change your mind and unaccepted this answer? Was anything incorrect?

Comment: what do you mean with unnaccepted?

Comment: @user6399 A&M told me you had 10 hours ago, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 6):

The rules together means the following.

Assume I am dying of a fatal disease and expected to die in 14 days. If I would write that I would die of sexual exhaustion in 21 days, I would still die of the original disease in 14 days before the book can come into effect assuming the cause of death is reasonable.

If I put that someone will die in 24 days of "insert horrific image here", it will not occur as stated.  When I remember that rule tommorrow and write that you will die of the same thing on that date... well... it will not be fun to be you.  If you want to avoid that after reading the death note, I guess you can kill yourself and the deathnote will not stop you as that is the end of your normal lifespan.  Note: you should have brought a pen so you can edit the entry.  That works.

Comment: so it would work right?

Comment: 2hat specifically are you asking it it would work? You cant say John will due in 2315 or anything.

Comment: But if i would write a death date, thats not beyond his lifespan, it would work?

Comment: I'd within 23 days and does not contradict any other rules.  There are over 100.

Comment: The way I interpret this, the "23 day rule" refers only to when you write a disease or "disease" as the cause of death with a specified time and no specified disease. It is basically saying that the specified time must be within 23 days of being written (perhaps something to do with the lunar cycle?) if you are writing disease as the cause of death.

Comment: You'd be interpreting it wrong. It applies when I write any cause of death except if the cause takes longer than 23 days to kill you because i wrote "death from disease". You cant die from brain cancer in 23days so you will get brain cancer within 23days whether you know it or not and die of it in a reasonable time (a couple of years).

Comment: so you could write dies from bradykardie and the person would die from this disease?

Comment: There are other questions about that in this site but yes if he wont die of something else first, it was already possible, and it doesnt contradict otger rules. You cannot specify when he dies if brady if it is after 23 days. Look up the death note rules.

Comment: people with bradykardie can have long lives. The victim will live much longer than 23 days.^^

Comment: If they would already die normally from cancer in 5 years and brady takes 10, they will still die from the cancer in 5. It can't extend their lives as I keep saying. But yes, it could have an effect a long time out via this.

Comment: well bradykardie takes longer than 10 years. but yes, i know that the death note cant extend the life of a person.^^

Comment: *if you put that you will die in 24 days it will not occur*. Where did you read that nothing would happen? I would think he would die within (6 minutes) and 40 seconds. Because once the name is written in the book, he will die according to XI.

Comment: Likely you are right on that (interpretation of deathnote wont work) but I dont remember any examples anyways. Editted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like I pointed out [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/40973/33164), the 23 days rule does not work that way. If the time of death is later than the natural one, the natural death will happen. If the time of death is before the natural one, it will either be a heart attack or the specified death.

The death note works for every time of death between the moment of entry and the natural time of death. The 23 days rule just specifies that one can't manipulate the victims for more than 23 days before their death including giving the victim a specified disease that takes more than 23 days to kill the victim.