# How long can you manipulate a person with a Death Note?

Tags: death-note

> If you write die of disease with a specific disease's name and the person's time of death, there must be a sufficient amount of time for the disease to progress. If the set time is too tight, the victim will die of a heart attack after 6 minutes and 40 seconds after completing the Death Note.

Let's say Y has a Death Note. He also has Shinigami Eyes, and because he's a genius he can read in Shinigami time. So he wants to kill Z.

He writes:

> Z, bradykardie, dies of bradykardie at 11:59 on this date: 25.07.2062. Till he dies, he will always do whatever the person he knows as A tells him to do.

(Yes, Z is destined to die at the mentioned date.)

(A won't die, since he already wrote his own name in his Death Note.)

Would this work?

Comment: Don't forget about the [23 day rule](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVII), mentioned right after the section you quoted.

Comment: @キルア The 23 day rule only counts when you don't write the name of a disease.

Comment: @AnonymUser incorrect, it counts for anything. [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13217/1587) goes into detail about the 23-day rule using examples which aren't diseases

Comment: @Memor-X Actually, chck the wiki. [Rule 28](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVIII) "If you write die of disease like before with a specific disease's name, but without a specific time, if it takes more than 24 days for the human to die the 23 day rule will not take effect and the human will die at an adequate time depending on the disease."

Answer (score 9):

This would not work, because you can only manipulate a person for a maximum of 23 days with the Death Note. This is therefore straightforwardly called the **23 day rule**.

As the [27th rule of the Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVII) states:

> The Death Note can only operate within 23 days (in the human calendar). This is called the 23 day rule.

As mentioned by Laiseran in the comments, **there is indeed one exception to this rule**. Although not directly relevant to your example, the 23 day rule can indeed be bypassed. If you write down a specific disease as the cause of death, but do not specify a specific time of death, the time of death will be unknown to the writer. The time of death will never be after the day that the victim's lifespan would run out, but if enough time remained, the Death Note will give the disease time to take effect. Since it might take more than 23 days for the specific disease to take effect, the human might thus be controlled longer than 23 days.

As the [28th rule of the Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVIII) states:

> If you write die of disease like before with a specific disease's name, but without a specific time, if it takes more than 24 days for the human to die the 23 day rule will not take effect and the human will die at an adequate time depending on the disease.