# Can a person do the shinigami eye deal without losing half of his lifespan?

Tags: death-note

Let's say, Bob has a death note. He gives up ownership, so that another one with shinigami eyes can tell him his lifespan. Bob is a genius, so he can calculate his death date. He writes his own name in it.

Bob Hyrule, Bradykardie, 2.3.2034.

He set his death date, by killing himself with a disease. Now he makes the shinigami eye deal. Will he die earlier?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work due to the 23 day rule.

> ### [How to use XXVII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVII)
>
> 2. If you write, die of disease for the cause of death, but only write a specific time of death without the actual name of disease, the human will die from an adequate disease. But the Death Note can only operate within 23 days (in the human calendar). This is called the 23 day rule.

Now lets say the person's lifespan will end in 23 days or less. Then the question could be rephrased as *What would happen to a person whose name is written in a DN, but whose lifespan is recalculated to be before the date written in that DN?* This could be caused by both the shinigami deal or by indirect influence of other people's deaths by DN. In this case we would again end up at the situation where a person's lifespan is before the date set in the death note and as we know from [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/909/6166), it is impossible to *increase your lifespan by killing yourself with the death note.*

### [How to use VLII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LVII)

> 1. In the Death Note, you cannot set the death date longer than the victim's original life span. Even if the victim's death is set in the Death Note beyond his/her original life span, the victim will die before the set time.

Therefore **I'd assume Bob to die within 11 days and a half**.

Comment: If you write die of disease like before with a specific disease's name, but without a specific time, if it takes more than 24 days for the human to die the 23 day rule will not take effect and the human will die at an adequate time depending on the disease.

Comment: @darkyagami you did specify a specific date though.

Comment: @DarkYagami If you don't specify a specific date, the answer is obvious, because a person will never die after the end of its lifespan, so the person would again lose half of its lifespan

Comment: but rule LVIII says that the death of a human can somtimes manipulate the life of another human and lengthend his life span. 
for example, if someone dies today by a murder und u kill the murderer with the DN before the murder happens, than the lifespan of the victim will expand

Comment: @Mintri yes. Thats true, but at the time the deal is done, his lifespan will drop to half. It can increase again later, but it will still drop to half.

Comment: i didn't say that this wouldn't be the case, since you can always die from a hearth attack :D

Comment: @mintri i didnt understand your comment then. Was something wrong in my answer according to you?

Comment: no, in the case with the deseas your answer is right, but i think with the rule LVIII you can expand you life time after the deal, if you deas isn't a heart attack or similar. i just felt like to add this here :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it was after all a Shinigami's book so probably not but lets go the logical way. If you set your death date at 22 days after this day then you die 22 days later. Then you make the Shinigami eye deal. Your current lifespan is 22 day because you set it at that day so then after making the deal you lose half so that means 11 day out and your left with only 11 days to live. So judging by this logic I think that you can not make the eye deal with out losing half your lifespan.